# localhost won't load after adding directives to httpd on WAMP Apache 2.2xx

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, .htaccess, httpd, hosts

I am not very experienced with configuring **httpd**, and I am following a tutorial to view my site w/ domain name under localhost. My localhost just blanks out and my apache services won't restart.

I checked all of my paths and they are correct.

I am editing the w**indows/system32/drivers/etc/host**s file and my apache httpd file.

This is what I am putting in my hosts file:
**127.0.0.1       www.cars_v1.0.com.localhost**

And in the footer of my httpd file I am putting this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
ServerName www.cars_v1.0.com.localhost
```

```
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\symfony\cars_v1.0\web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "C:\wamp\www\symfony\cars_v1.0\web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf C:\wamp\www\symfony\cars_v1.0\lib\vendor\symfony-1.4.8\data\web\sf
  <Directory "C:\wamp\www\symfony\cars_v1.0\lib\vendor\symfony-1.4.8\data\web\sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: For more clarification, I am using WAMP and apache 2.2xx

Answer (score 1):

Duh! I solved this. I accidentally had a

```
<!--
```

tag in the directive!